# Let $\theta >0$ be unknown and suppose that $(X,Y)$ is uniform over the triangular region with vertices at $(0,0)$,$(\theta, 0)$, and $(0,\theta)$.

Tags: probability, statistics, sufficient-statistics

Let $\theta >0$ be unknown and suppose that $(X,Y)$ is uniform over the triangular region with vertices at $(0,0)$,$(\theta, 0)$, and $(0,\theta)$. Let $(X_i,Y_i)$ be iid as $(X,Y)$. Find a one dimensional sufficient statistic $T$ for $\theta$, and prove it's sufficient.

My thoughts: I want to find the likelihood function then try to separate as two functions so that I can get a statistic, but in this case, I have difficulty finding the density function. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: The equation line forming the upper boundary of the triangular region suggests that one should consider $T_i=X_i+Y_i$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Thank you! But here you only consider the boundary. Could you be more explicit? Thanks!

Comment: As the 3 vertices of the support is given, you know the equation of the 3 edges of the support on the $(x,y)$-plane. Turn these equations into inequalities, such that the intersecting region of the associated half-planes is the support. And this will be the constraint in the indicator function for your likelihood function.